# How to access labels with TFF

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning, federated

I was following this [Image classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) and [Text Generation tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation). So I've implemented transfer learning with fine-tuning on my dataset but I don't know how to access labels whenever I am doing predictions.
I transformed my data into the right shape (tf.data.Dataset) so I am using the Keras model for predictions. So for example if I want just to predict one label: `keras_model.predict(federated_train_data[0])`

federated_train_data consists of following elements:

```
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))
```

First Tensor is an image shape and the second one represents encoded labels.

My goal is to illustrate what are true and predicted labels of an image, for example:([Predicted classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5KwL.png))

TLDR: Is there a way that you can access just labels when you have tf.data.Dataset?

Comment: how did you make predictions on tff model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `federated_train_data` is a `tf.data.Dataset` whose `.element_spec` property returns:

```py
(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None),
 TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))
```

Then iterating over the dataset is possible:

```py
# Get the first batch
first_batch = next(iter(federated_train_data)) 

# Examine all batches
for batch in federated_train_data:
  print(batch)
```

From the `.element_spec` we know each batch is a 2-tuple of `(features, labels)`, so we can get the labels using the second index:

```py
labesl = first_batch[1]

# Or unpack
features, labels = first_batch
```

Combining this with the model predictions:

```py
for batch in federated_train_data:
  features, labels = batch
  predictions = keras_model.predict(features)
  # Now we have all three pieces: features, labels, and predictions.
```